# Is there a pure Perl module for AES?

Tags: perl, cryptography, cpan

Is there a pure Perl module for AES?

Comment: encryption is very performance sensitive. i would pick c++ for this task. why pure Perl?

Comment: @Andrey: most performance-critical or algorithm-heavy modules, such as encyption libraries, have XS code embedded, which is just as fast as C/C++.

Comment: @Ether, well this doesn't sound as pure perl

Comment: Why does it have to be pure Perl?

Comment: I use windows os don't want the installation of the module clash with some dlls on my system

Answer (score 7):

[Crypt::Rijndael_PP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-Rijndael_PP) (Rijndael being the algorithm underlying [AES](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)).  No idea about its quality.